# Spock tests running out of permgen in teamcity

Tags: java, teamcity, spock

We have several Spock tests that, when run together in a build, fail because of "permgen space." I should note that some tests do pass and others do not. I did the obvious first step and tried increasing the java params for permgen and maxPermSize to no avail. I did this by going to "build parameters" in teamCity, making a new parameter called "env.JAVA_OPTS," and placing this string as the value:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

We are using Ant as a build tool. Here is the target for running the tests. By the way, I did try it in forked mode:

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTests">
        <junit>
          <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
          <classpath path="${testBuildDir}" />
          <classpath refid="classpath" />  
                  <classpath path="${deployClassesDir}" />        
          <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${testBuildDir}">
                <include name="**/*Spec.class"/>                                
            </fileset>
          </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

I tried isolating the problem by ignoring all the tests inside of a test class, and activating them one by one. This resulted in inconsistent results.
Here is an example of one test. The first time I took off the "Ignore" annotation, it passed. I then took off the annotation for another test, which failed. I put back the "Ignore" annotation and the first test failed, which surprised me. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
class CitiUserPasswordValidatorSpec extends Specification{

@Shared def username = "username1";
@Shared def citiUserPasswordValidator = new ident.web.citi.CitiUserPasswordValidator()
private String invalidPassword;


@Ignore
def "Password is valid." (){
    setup:
        def facesContextMock = Mock(FacesContext)
        def uiComponentMock = Mock(UIComponent)
        def uiInputMock = Mock(UIInput)
        def uiViewRootMock = Mock(UIViewRoot)

        def password = "aBcqwe123"

        facesContextMock.getViewRoot() >> uiViewRootMock
        uiViewRootMock.findComponent("RtWindow:buttons:username") >> uiInputMock
        uiInputMock.getSubmittedValue() >> username
    when:
        citiUserPasswordValidator.validate(facesContextMock, uiComponentMock, password);
    then:
        notThrown ValidatorException
}...
```

Comment: The problem is most likely not related to this one class. How do you run the tests on TeamCity? Which build tool? How did you increase permgen settings?

Comment: Hi Peter, I added answers to your questions in my edit. And you are right, this happens for different classes as well.

Comment: You have to figure out the right way to set a higher permgen limit for the JVM that runs the tests. I suppose the Ant JUnit task has a configuration option for that, in particular if tests are run in forked mode.

Comment: That worked. I used fork="yes",forkmode="perBatch," and maxmemory="2048m." I did try using some Junit tag params earlier in ant, but it looks like maybe I didnt give it enough memory. If you respond, I will mark yours as the correct answer.